# Find a recurrence relation that counts the number of off-diagonal elements of an $n+1 × n+1$ matrix...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Find a recurrence relation that counts the number of off-diagonal elements of an $n+1 × n+1$ matrix. Solve this recurrence relation for an expression of the number of off diagonal entries as a function of $n$.

-For the first part of the question I got $M(n+1) = M(n) + 2n$.

-I am unsure how to solve this as a function of $n$, first off I am unsure if what I came up with is correct for first part and if so how to proceed with this. I am familiar with the auxiliary equation method but i am unsure how to approach this with a non-homogeneous piece $(2n)$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is a strange detour to find a _recurrence relation_ for this. Plainly there are $(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1$ elements in the matrix, of which $n+1$ are on the diagonal. Those remaining, $n^2+n=n(n+1)$ in all, are the off-diagonal elements.

Comment: I see what you mean, unfortunately this is on my final review and i just don't really see how to proceed but i want to know how to solve it in case something similar pops us.

Comment: Well, recurrences of the form $a_{n+1}=a_n+f(n)$ are extremely common -- in fact so common that there's a special notation for them: $$ a_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^n f(n) $$ and you may be better acquainted with techniques for solving them in that notation ...

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know the technique you're referring to, could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recursion is indeed correct.

To get a closed-form answer, write the recursion for different values of $n$ and sum them up, as follows:
\begin{align}
M(n+1) &= M(n) + 2n \\
M(n) &= M(n-1) + 2(n-1) \\
M(n-1) &= M(n-2) + 2(n-2) \\
\dots & \\
M(3) &= M(2) + 2(2) \\
M(2) &= M(1) + 2(1) \\
M(1) &= 0
\end{align}

After summing these up you get:
\begin{align}
& M(n+1) = 2\sum_{i=1}^n i = n(n+1) \\
\Rightarrow &M(n) = n(n-1)
\end{align}